# C# Custom control - class hierarchy and markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I am trying to create the custom grid control from the scratch. So I have created the class library project for it and started with

```
public class ServerControl1 : WebControl
{
}
```

Now, I have added this reference in my project. So in my aspx page it shows something like

```
<cc1:ServerControl1 runat="server" id="grid1" />
```

Now i want to defined the columns of this grid and also want to make it familier like asp gridview

```
<asp:GridView ....>
    <Columns>
          <TemplateFields>
 .....
```

Now to make such hierarchical structure GridView >> Columns >> TemplateFields, what class structure should I implement?

I am not much in to OOPS so any help will be much appreciated. I don't want to inherit the GridView control in my class as I am not going to use it and I don't know what over burden it will bring to my control.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link with a answer already posted. [Create custom control with nested tag like GridView >> Columns >> Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535380/create-custom-control-with-nested-tag-like-gridview-columns-paging)

Basically what you need is **not** Custom control but a **composite control** which should implement **CompositeControl, IScriptControl** IScriptcontrol is optional if you need AJAX support.

And then all your properties you will be able assign values in markup. Here is a MSDN link to create one as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12yydcke.aspx

Also you have to understand how to override **CreateChildControls** method in CompositeControl and how to create your control Hirearchy.

Frankly, there is quiet a bit of learning to do actually.